# Service Fabric Unit Tesitng a Reliable Actor Method which reads config info from Settings.xml and App.Config

Tags: unit-testing, azure-service-fabric, xunit

I am currently working on a Service Fabric project, where in one of our reliable actors we make calls to a SOAP service. For these calls we read a couple of parameters from the Actor's Settings.xml and also - the SOAP endpoint address and binding information from the App.config file (actually the latter is done implicitly by the generated service proxy class for the SOAP service).

Now I am trying to get the unit testing work with xUnit + ServiceFabric.Mocks. To test an Actor specific method I go through:
1) Creating a "MockCodePackageActivationContext"
2) Creating a "StatefulServiceContext" using the instance of the activation context in step 1.
3) Instantiate the Actor with the code below

```
MyActor target = new MyActor(
                new ActorService(
                    context: serviceContext,
                    actorTypeInfo: ActorTypeInformation.Get(typeof(MyActor)),
                    stateManagerFactory: (actorBase, stateProvider) => new MockActorStateManager()
                ),
                new ActorId(Guid.NewGuid())
            );
```

4) I call target.MyMethod() which breaks due to inability to read config info either from the Settings.xml or the App.config file

I made a test where target.MyMethod_Test() does not read anything from config and it was successful.

Anyone who stumbled upon similar thing? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a separate class that provides configuration data. Create an interface for it and then inject it in the Actor constructor, in Program Main. (Passing the service context into the new class for example.)

Also create a mock implementation of the interface and pass that one to the Actor for testing purposes.